# Questions before ordering The Key

Tags: support, fun, dark-mode, april-fools

I love [The Key](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/) and would like to order it but I have some questions:

[image: Image of "The Key" - keyboard with three white keys a button with the Stack Overflow logo, a "C", and a "V"]

1. The product shown has light keys. Does it come with dark keys to match the dark mode on Stack Overflow?
2. Can I use the light keyboard with dark mode? Or vice versa - a dark The Key (assuming it exists) with the light mode? Are there known compatibility issues?
3. The product description says 90 dB peak sound level. Is that guaranteed or just theoretical maximum? I live in an apartment building and nowadays work from home. I am concerned that it may not accurately notify my neighbours that I am programming©ⓥ right now. I usually just shout at the top of my lungs when I do it to let them know. I like keeping them informed. I am concerned that my neighbours might not be accurately and consistently reminded that I am programming©ⓥ.

Comment: I got the toaster when I tried to copy. I said what the heck is this before I noticed it must be April fools.

Comment: I, and a couple of other reviewers, did not choose "Off-topic" as our reason; it appears due to a majority choosing that reason.

Comment: The Key V2 is available: https://drop.com/buy/stack-overflow-the-key-v2-macropad

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The key does in fact come in dark mode (sold separate). It doesn't change automatically yet, but it may in a future release.
2. Copying text using the light mode product from a dark source should work, but it may result in minor l33t 5p3ak.
3. The 90 dB is the default volume. The volume can be configured to be louder by holding the Stack Overflow button for 6.9 seconds, then press the C key to increase volume or V key to decrease it. The Key supports all sound levels from -10 dB for super stealthy programming©ⓥ up to 1000 dB so aliens from beyond the observable universe can hear your programming©ⓥ skill.

Comment: THANK YOU. IT ALL WORKS GREAT. I INCREASED THE SOUND. BUT NOW I CAN BARELY HEAR ANYTHING. I ASSUME IT'S A BUG - HOPEFULLY IT GETS FIXED. 5 STARS

Comment: @VLAZ WHAT?  I CAN'T HEAR YOU.